# How to update view model on basis of ajax response in knockout js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel of state in which i have five fields out of five one field is hidden field .Which i want to be get updated whenever i am trigging an ajax request. my servlet respond a value . I want this value be get updated on the basis of ajax response. here is my viewmodel

```
var dummyData = [{ "nsc": "1", "name": "us", "bic": "united states", "identifier": "us" }, { "nsc": "2", "name": "europe", "bic": "europe", "identifier": "us" }, { "nsc": "3", "name": "aus", "bic": "aus", "identifier": "us" }];
function State(data) {
    this.nsc = ko.observable(data.nsc || "");
    this.nscto = ko.observable(data.nscto || "");
    this.bic = ko.observable(data.bic || "");
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name || "");
    this.hiddenField = ko.observable(data.identifier || "");
}
function StateViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.States = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.PopulateStates = ko.computed(function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(dummyData, function (item) {
            self.States.push(new State(item));
        });
    });
    self.nsc = ko.observable();
    self.nscto = ko.observable();
    self.bic = ko.observable();
    self.hiddenField = ko.observable();
    self.name = ko.observable();
}
```

Here is my addState function on which i am making an ajax request

```
self.addState = function (state) {
    var stateData = ko.toJSON({ data: new State({ nsc: self.nsc(), nscto: self.nscto(), bic: self.bic(), name: self.name() }) });
    $.ajax
        ({
            data: "action=" + "addarea" + "&jsonData=" + stateData,
            url: '/bin/stateUpdate/add',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                var identifier = data['identifier'];
                alert(identifier); // checking servlet reponse
                self.hiddenField(identifier);
                self.States.push(new State({
                    nsc: self.nsc(),
                    nscto: self.nscto(),
                    bic: self.bic(),
                    name: self.name(),
                    hiddenField: self.hiddenField(identifier)
                }));
            },

            error: function (exception) {
                alert("fail");

            }
        });

    /* $.post("/bin/stateUpdate/add", stateData, function(returnedData) {
          bank.hiddenField(returnedData);
          })*/


};
```

i want to update hiddenField on the basis of value getting from servlet.and addstate function is inside viewmodel. How can i set this value second when i am trying making ajax request using Knockout method $.post it is not working. can anybody help ?

Comment: Is it intentional you're calling state.hiddenField and not self.hiddenField?  I expected self.hiddenField(identifier)...

Comment: i update it paul thanks

Comment: No worries - working now?

Comment: tried it but didn't work

Comment: What is your JSON look like, and do you get the alert in your success callback ?  Is the self.addState function declared inside StateViewModel or somewhere else. ( ie check the value of `self` in your AJAX success callback )

Comment: Hi Robert i wrote my AddState method in viewModel for Clearity i wrote it separate here and in my laer i am getting the value of identifier but it is not getting set

Comment: Can you provide a simple JSFiddle?  Make a dummy for your ajax call that just updates the model with JSON.

Comment: sorry paul i dont know how to create a dummy ajax request :( i don't know wher i am lacking because i didn't getting any error on console also

Comment: The easiest way to simulate an ajax call response is to use `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0)`.  The callback function is your success function with a hardcoded data value

Comment: Should this line be new Bank or State  `self.States.push(new Bank({`

Comment: If so, you are pushing in an object as data containing the field `hiddenField` but reading `data.identifier` in the state constructor